# PHP compare and conditional insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `oc_product` and `oc_product_description`.
I'd like to compare two columns between these two tables, the columns are `product_id` for both.
If the `product_id` from `oc_product` isnt equal to `product_id` from `oc_product_description` to insert a new entry in `oc_product_description` where `product_id` = what is in `oc_product` but not in `oc_product_description`.

Also, rest of `oc_product_description` columns must be filled with entry from `oc_product` like the entry with `product_id` that cant be find in `oc_product_description`:

`product_id = 1440` (value from `oc_product`)

`name = Aquolina` (value from `oc_product` based on product_id that couldnt be found in `oc_product_description`)

What i've tried so far:

```
$insert_oc_desc = "INSERT INTO oc_product_description (product_id, language_id, name, description, tag, meta_title, meta_description, meta_keyword)
        VALUES (SELECT product_id FROM oc_product WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM oc_product_description), 2, '" . $model . "', '&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; text-align: justify;&quot;&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;', '" . $model . "," . $man_name . "', '" . $model . " ,Pret " . $updated_price . " lei', '', '" . $model . "," . $man_name . "')";
```

Comment: Why are you inserting a tag in the database? lol

Comment: Is this important? I ask how to compare two columns and insert in a table if not the same, also, other columns must be related to the product_id that couldnt be found in the table where i want to insert

Comment: No no, it's just that this is sort of uncommon. (in my point of view)

Comment: In my point of view too, but it wasnt created by me like this, i wouldnt created as this either